# Cannot query the value of task ':data-local:compileDebugKotlin' property 'moduleName' because it has no value available

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

I'm working on a multi module project. I recently upgraded the kotlin version to 1.9.0 and compose compiler to 1.5.2. Gradle plugin version 8.1.1

Since the upgrade I keep getting the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':data-local'.
> Cannot query the value of task ':data-local:compileDebugKotlin' property 'moduleName' because it has no value available.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':data-local'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)...
```

Here's my data-local **build.gradle** file:

```
plugins {
    alias libs.plugins.android.library
    alias libs.plugins.kotlin.android
    alias libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt
    alias libs.plugins.hilt.android
    alias libs.plugins.ksp
}

android {
    namespace 'com.zacle.data_local'
    compileSdk ProjectConfig.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk ProjectConfig.minSdk
        targetSdk ProjectConfig.targetSdk

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.zacle.data_local.database.HiltTestRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = ProjectConfig.jvmTarget
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(path: ":data-repository"))
    implementation(project(path: ":core:model"))
    implementation(project(path: ":core:common"))

    implementation libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android

    // Room
    implementation libs.androidx.room.runtime
    implementation libs.androidx.room.ktx
    ksp libs.androidx.room.compiler

    // Hilt
    implementation libs.hilt.android
    kapt libs.hilt.compiler

    // Unit tests
    testImplementation libs.junit4
    testImplementation libs.kotlinx.coroutines.test
    testImplementation libs.mockito.kotlin

    // Instrumented tests
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.test.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.kotlinx.coroutines.test
    androidTestImplementation libs.mockito.kotlin
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.test.core
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.test.runner
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.test.rule
    androidTestImplementation libs.truth
    androidTestImplementation libs.hilt.android.testing
    kaptAndroidTest libs.hilt.android.compiler

    coreLibraryDesugaring libs.desugar.jdk.libs
}
```

Could you help me figure out what the moduleName property error comes from and how to fix it?

Comment: Fixed. Error was related to gradle versions mismatch

Comment: I am getting the same error after updating all dependencies. Which versions-mismatch caused this for you, exactly?

Comment: Nevermind, I had to update the kotlin gradle-plugin and the ksp-gradle-plugin for the error to go away.

Comment: @Zacle how exactly did you fix this. can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 16):

Had similar issue when I was updating my project dependencies and updated kotlin from 1.8.21 to 1.9.20.

I realized the problem was caused by KSP plugin (com.google.devtools.ksp) and was resolved by updating that dependency too from 1.8.21-1.0.11 to 1.9.20-1.0.14.

```
plugins {
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.20-1.0.14" apply false
}
```

My gradle sync error was:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot query the value of task ':app:compileDevDebugKotlin' property 'moduleName' because it has no value available.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: Cannot query the value of task ':app:compileDevDebugKotlin' property 'moduleName' because it has no value available.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateOwnPresentValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspGradleSubplugin$applyToCompilation$kspTaskProvider$1$1.invoke(KspSubplugin.kt:435)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the latest, as of February 2024:

id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.17" apply false

Latest version is announced here: https://github.com/google/ksp/releases